# c# Devexpress Gridview FocusedRow Wrong Choise After Search

Tags: c#, gridview, devexpress

I am working on a c# windows form project with devexpress.

I created a list with GridView and list items. That is ok. I am using the code below to get the ID value of the row I clicked on from the list on the gridview and the code is working.

```
        DataRow dr = gridView1.GetDataRow(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle);
        vID = dr["ID"].ToString();
```

But when i search something and if there is only one result, the problem begins. In such a case, when I select a single line, the wrong ID is selected.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If you update your ID in [FocusedRowChanged](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_FocusedRowChangedtopic) event,It may get old value after dataSourceChanged.

According to this ticket:[Grid - How to select a row after find](https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/t302458/grid-how-to-select-a-row-after-find)

you should also handle [GridView.FocusedRowObjectChanged](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_FocusedRowObjectChangedtopic) event